# Get the Folder / File list + size from .BAT file / Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some code to fetch the all folder's list and size from any given path.
Condition is if file size is less than 1GB, it should give the size MB else GB (which is working perfectly)

Only issue is I want to get filelist and size also. But it giving me only folders. like if my Input folder have 10 folders and 5 files, this code is giving only 10 folder list and size. I want all.

I am attaching my code here. someone please check and change if needed. I want this list to be sorted alphabetically also. If anyone can give me powershell code with the same functionality that also will be okay, because this code is little bit lengthy.

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "InputFolder=F:\Input_Folder"
set "OutputFolder=F:\Output_Folder"
set "TempFolder=F:\Temp"
del "%OutputFolder%"\WS_list.txt
  if not defined InputFolder set "InputFolder=%cd%"

    for /d %%a in ("%InputFolder%\*") do (
        set "size=0"
        for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        call :GetUnit !size! unit
        call :ConvertBytes !size! !unit! newsize
        echo(%%~nxa - !newsize! !unit!
        endlocal
    ) >> "%OutputFolder%"\WS_list.txt

endlocal
pause
exit /b

:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=/1024
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=/1024/1024/1024
if "%~2" EQU "TB" set val=/1024/1024/1024/1024
> "%TempFolder%"\tmp.vbs echo wsh.echo FormatNumber(eval(%~1%val%),1)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo "%TempFolder%"\tmp.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~3=%%a
del "%TempFolder%"\tmp.vbs
exit /b


:GetUnit bytes return
set byt=00000000000%1X
set TB=000000000001099511627776X
if %1 LEQ 1024 set "unit=Bytes"
if %1 GTR 1024   set "unit=KB"
if %1 GTR 1048576  set "unit=MB"
if %1 GTR 1073741824  set "unit=GB"
if %byt:~-14% GTR %TB:~-14% set "unit=TB"
endlocal & set %~2=%unit%
exit /b
```

Comment: Removed `powershell` tag and changed the title to `Batch`.

Comment: I have removed, for the second time your [[tag:dos]] tag. Please do not add invalid tags to your questions. Your provided code does not, and will not work on a Disk Operating System, PC-DOS, MS-DOS etc. It is for Windows only, and the [[tag:windows]] is already included.

Comment: can anyone help me here for the solution?